# Push notification with "content-available" : 1 payload not always calling application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:

Tags: ios, push-notification

In an iPhone app that we are building we are using the `"content-available" : 1` parameter in the push notification payload to call `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` in the app delegate as soon as a push notification arrives. The push notification is not silent; we are also using the "alert" and "sound" parameters to notify the user. I have added the `remote-notification` value to the `UIBackgroundModes` array in my Info.plist file.

I've noticed that the `"content-available" : 1` parameter always calls the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method when we are using the development APNS environment when a push notification arrives (gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, this is what is being used when I'm running the app from Xcode). Unfortunately this is not the case when I distribute the app via TestFlight in iTunes Connect (in this case the production APNS environment is being used, gateway.push.apple.com). In production the calling of `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is very unreliable, sometimes it's being called and sometimes it isn't, even though the push notification always arrives (of course I know this because it isn't a hidden notification, I see the message and hear the sound).

Has anybody else also had this experience? Could iOS be more 'conservative' in calling `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` in a production environment to minimize impact on battery life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple take care about users and check that apps do not drain device's battery, especially if in background. If you app asks too lot resources it likely that system will postpone your app's requests to lower priority queue. This is the extraction from documentation

> As soon as you finish processing the notification, you must call the block in the handler parameter or your app will be terminated. Your app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to process the notification and call the specified completion handler block. In practice, you should call the handler block as soon as you are done processing the notification. The system tracks the elapsed time, power usage, and data costs for your app’s background downloads. **Apps that use significant amounts of power when processing remote notifications may not always be woken up early to process future notifications**.

And there is the second moment to notice

> However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.